# Python - Talking to an open program through terminal

Tags: python, linux, terminal, communication

I have been using **os.system()** to communicate with terminal, which works perfectly. However, with it I'm opening a program that needs to have commands written to it, and I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Basically, I'm running:

```
tleap -f leaprc
```

This opens the program in terminal, and it presents:

```
*non-important code*
>
```

Now, I need to start sending commands to the program, but I can't find anything that will write to the right of the **>**.
**os.system()** doesn't work for this, and, not being Python-savvy, I'm clueless.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `subprocess.Popen`

Here's a bit of sample code using python as the program.

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['python'],stdin = subprocess.PIPE,stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.stdin.write('print "Hello, world!"\n')
>>> p.stdin.write('for i in range(10):\n    print i\n')
>>> p.communicate()
('Hello, world!\r\n0\r\n1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n5\r\n6\r\n7\r\n8\r\n9\r\n', None)
```

If you're running on Linux, the easiest way to send your command to the terminal is to use the `shlex.split` function.  So you would call

```
p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('tleaf -f leaprc'),stdin = subprocess.PIPE,stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

At least in my experience, calling `communicate` on a process object closes it, so you only get one chance to read the output.  If this is not ok for you, I'd look into the [`pexpect`](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) module.

Comment: When I tried using the subprocess.Popen method, it worked when I put 'tleap' as the program. However, when I entered 'tleap -f leaprc', I got **OSError: [Errno 13]**. I can't understand why, though, because it worked just fine when I was opening it with **os.system()**. I got the same error when using shlex.

Comment: One thing that might help is using the `shell = True` argument to `subprocess.Popen`

Answer (score 0):

Or try to use the **python-pexpect** package instead of **Subprocess**. Much easier and friendly.

```
import pexpect

mypassword='somepassword'

child = pexpect.run('passwd guille') child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline(mypassword)
```